# GUI control flow and callbacks in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

My background is mainly in JavaScript, where functions are first-class objects and I can pass them around easily as callbacks.  That is very much the *way* of JavaScript.

Now I am attempting to build a simple Java app.  The problem at hand is to (1) use Swing to let the user browse to a file to open, and then (2) do some stuff with it.  Let's say I have a method like this

```
void doStuff(File file) {
    //stuff
}
```

that needs to run on the file chosen by the user.  In JavaScript,  the doStuff function would simply be passed as a callback.  How would one do this in Java?

I'm aware that it is possible to do callbacks in Java by, say, making a Callback interface with a void run() method.  But is that idiomatic?  How *should* this kind of thing be done?  How would an experienced Java programmer choose to do it?

Also, when I use callbacks, it looks like nearly everything happens on the Event Dispatch Thread.  I suppose I could, from the EDT, create a new third thread, but it seems like my doStuff function should be executing on the main thread.  And I can't figure out any way to make that happen.  Nor do I know if it's necessary or desirable to make it happen.

Comment: Much will depend on how complex your "do stuff" is. For instance solutions would differ if it is Java stuff, and can run on the Swing event thread without blocking it, vs if you're instead running long-running code that needs to run off of the event thread. Solutions can vary between using a Runnable, a Callable, or a SwingWorker with a PropertyChangeListener added to it.

Comment: Hm.  Those are some things I can read about.

Comment: What *exactly* does "do stuff* do?

Comment: Put simply, "do stuff" will parse and import data from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put simply, "do stuff" will parse and import data from the file.

Since this involves file or resource input, then it should not be done on the EDT. The best solution IMO would be to

- do the importing and parsing within the `doInBackground()` method of a SwingWorker
- add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker
- have this listener listen to the worker's state property, specifically for a new value of SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE
- in this listener, you'll then be notified when the worker has completed its task. You'll want to be sure to call `get()` on the SwingWorker when its done, so you can get any end value that you want it to produce, and so you can capture and respond to any and all exceptions that might have occurred during its run.

For more on this, please check out the tutorial -- [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

---

> Do you suggest using SwingWorker mainly so that this process doesn't take place on the EDT, thereby locking up the user interface?

Yes. Any thread would serve that purpose though, but the main advantage of using the SwingWorker is because while it will run the process in a background thread, it also has great mechanisms for providing end and interim results **on** the EDT, as well as built-in functionality to monitor progress.

Comment: Do you suggest using SwingWorker mainly so that this process doesn't take place on the EDT, thereby locking up the user interface?